# .NET Core EF One to Many / Many to Many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a problem: I have seen other posts here but they don't seem to work.

I have a `userClass`:

```
public class UserClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int deskId { get; set; }

    public int departmentId { get; set; }
    public bool isManager { get; set; }
    public int managerId { get; set; }
  
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string emailAdress { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public Desk desk { get; set; }
}
```

My class Desk looks like

```
public class Desk
{
    public int deskId { get; set; }
    public int deskNumber { get; set; }
    public int floorNumber { get; set; }
    public bool isOffice { get; set; }
}
```

I have a stored procedure where I call everything but it returns desk as null. It doesn't seem like Entity Framework is recognizing the class `desk`.

This is what my dbContext looks like

```
public DbSet<UserClass> UserClass { get; set; }
public DbSet<Desk> Desk { get; set; }
```

And this is my migration

```
modelBuilder.Entity("UserService.Models.Desk", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("deskId")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int")
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<int>("deskNumber")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<int>("floorNumber")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<bool>("isOffice")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.HasKey("deskId");

                b.ToTable("Desk");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("UserService.Models.UserClass", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int")
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<int>("departmentId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<int?>("deskId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<string>("emailAdress")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("firstName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<bool>("isManager")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<string>("lastName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<int>("managerId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("departmentId");

                b.HasIndex("deskId");

                b.ToTable("UserClass");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("UserService.Models.UserClass", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("UserService.Models.Desk", "desk")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("deskId");
            });
```

Do I need to set up a 3rd "join" table as I have seen examples of? Or could I solve this any other way?

I shouldn't need the stored procedure, but I have also tried to query the `userClass` table itself

BR
M.B

Comment: can you please include your actual code and also the main DbContextConfiguration class rather then migration code?

Comment: What does the stored procedure return? Also show the code that calls the sproc. Note, however, that a sproc is not composable, something like `Include` isn't possible.